# Make an array of array from array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object

I just want to make an array from my data and list down each material base on the status.
My array show below..

```
let data = [
        {
            Name: 'House 1', 
            Details:[
                {Materials: 'Door', Status: 'Delivered'},
                {Materials: 'Closet', Status: 'Pending'},
                {Materials: 'Chair', Status: 'Pending'},
                {Materials: 'Kitchen', Status: 'Delivered'},
                {Materials: 'Door Knob', Status: 'Delivered'}
            ]
        },

        {
            Name: 'House 2', 
            Details:[
                {Materials: 'Cabinet', Status: 'Delivered'},
                {Materials: 'Kitchen', Status: 'Delivered'},
                {Materials: 'Door', Status: 'Ongoing'},
                {Materials: 'Chair', Status: 'Ongoing'},
                {Materials: 'Window', Status: 'Cancelled'}
            ]
        },
        //Other codes here...
    ];
```

I want to list down the status for each material.

Expected Output:

```
[
    0: 'House 1'
        [
            0: 'Delivered': [ 0: 'Door', 1: 'Kitchen', 2: 'Door Knob' ]
            1: 'Pending': [ 0: 'Closet, 1: 'Chair' ]
        ]
    1: 'House 2'
        [
            0: 'Cancelled': [ 0: 'Window' ]
            1: 'Delivered': [ 0: 'Cabinet', 1: 'Kitchen' ]
            2: 'Ongoing': [ 0: 'Chair', 1: 'Door' ]
        ]
]
//where 0:, 1:, 2: is the index of each array(*nested array)
//i just added index like what you see in console.log(*but it's not required to show in final output)
```

I'm trying to use forEach and .reduce but it seems my code doesn't go well.

I hope you can resolve my problem :)

Comment: in the final do you need an array or an object in the form `{House1: [], House2:[]....}`. or is the shape like `{House1:{Cancelled:[],Delivered:[]}, House2:{...}`

Comment: If possible i need an array result = [ House1: [ ], House2: [ ] ], But if that's the wrong way, i go with an object.

Comment: `[ House1: [ ], House2: [ ] ]` is not valid js unfortunately

Comment: I see. Thank's for clarification. But if you could suggest, what will be the function i should use to get the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure you want cannot be represented solely by arrays; use objects instead for key-value pairs. You can use `Array#reduce` to group elements by their status into a single object.

```js
let data=[{Name:"House 1",Details:[{Materials:"Door",Status:"Delivered"},{Materials:"Closet",Status:"Pending"},{Materials:"Chair",Status:"Pending"},{Materials:"Kitchen",Status:"Delivered"},{Materials:"Door Knob",Status:"Delivered"}]},{Name:"House 2",Details:[{Materials:"Cabinet",Status:"Delivered"},{Materials:"Kitchen",Status:"Delivered"},{Materials:"Door",Status:"Ongoing"},{Materials:"Chair",Status:"Ongoing"},{Materials:"Window",Status:"Cancelled"}]},];
let res = Object.fromEntries(data.map(o => [o.Name, o.Details.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  (acc[curr.Status] ??= []).push(curr.Materials);
  return acc;
}, {})]));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks close to what you asked for. It is all arrays.

```js
let data=[
    {
        Name: 'House 1', 
        Details:[
            {Materials: 'Door', Status: 'Delivered'},
            {Materials: 'Closet', Status: 'Pending'},
            {Materials: 'Chair', Status: 'Pending'},
            {Materials: 'Kitchen', Status: 'Delivered'},
            {Materials: 'Door Knob', Status: 'Delivered'}
        ]
    },
    {
        Name: 'House 2', 
        Details:[
            {Materials: 'Cabinet', Status: 'Delivered'},
            {Materials: 'Kitchen', Status: 'Delivered'},
            {Materials: 'Door', Status: 'Ongoing'},
            {Materials: 'Chair', Status: 'Ongoing'},
            {Materials: 'Window', Status: 'Cancelled'}
        ]
    }
];
let newData=[];
for(let i in data){
    let delivered=data[i].Details.filter(e=>{if(e.Status==="Delivered")return true});
    let Pending=data[i].Details.filter(e=>{if(e.Status==="Pending")return true});
    let Ongoing=data[i].Details.filter(e=>{if(e.Status==="Ongoing")return true});
    let Cancelled=data[i].Details.filter(e=>{if(e.Status==="Cancelled")return true});
    let t=[data[i].Name,[],[],[],[]];
    for(let x in delivered){
        t[1].push(delivered[x].Materials);
    }
    for(let x in Pending){
        t[2].push(Pending[x].Materials);
    }
    for(let x in Ongoing){
        t[3].push(Ongoing[x].Materials);
    }
    for(let x in Cancelled){
        t[4].push(Cancelled[x].Materials);
    }
    newData.push(t);
}
console.log(newData);
```